# having an issue writing activerecord for nested select for codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am attempting to translate a nested query to active record on codeigniter.

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, snapshot_id, snapshot_guid, image, subject, name, brands.brand_id, brand_guid, date_sent FROM
        (SELECT snapshot_id, snapshot_guid, snapshots.brand_id, image, subject, snapshots.status, date_sent 
        FROM snapshots INNER JOIN brands ON snapshots.brand_id = brands.brand_id 
        WHERE (snapshots.status = 1 AND brands.status = 1) AND DATE(date_sent) = '2015-2-9'
        ORDER BY date_sent DESC) snapshots
    INNER JOIN brands
    ON snapshots.brand_id = brands.brand_id
    GROUP BY snapshots.brand_id
    ORDER BY date_sent DESC;
```

It is producing the correct results, but can't seem to get the active record correctly working.

Here what I have so far:

```
if(is_null($date))
      $date = date('Y-m-d');

    /* sub query */
    $this->db->select('snapshot_id, snapshot_guid, image, snapshots.brand_id, subject, snapshots.status, date_sent');
    $this->db->from('snapshots');
    $this->db->join('brands', 'snapshots.brand_id = brands.brand_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('snapshots.status', 1);
    $this->db->where('brands.status', 1);
    $this->db->where('DATE(date_sent)', $date);
    $this->db->order_by('date_sent', 'desc');
    $this->db->get();
    $sub = $this->db->last_query();

    $this->db->select('count(*) as count, snapshot_id, snapshot_guid, image, name, snapshots.brand_id, brand_guid, date_sent')
    //$this->db->from($sub, null, false);
    $this->db->join('brands', 'snapshots.brand_id = brands.brand_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('brands.status', 1);
    $this->db->group_by('snapshots.brand_id');
    $this->db->order_by('date_sent', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit($count);
    $query = $this->db->get($sub.' as snapshots');
    return $query->result();
```

The error is here: $query = $this->db->get($sub .'as snapshots');

It is adding an additional apostrophe in the subquery. ex:

```
FROM (`SELECT` `snapshot_id`, `snapshot_guid`, `image`, `snapshots`.`brand_id`, `subject`, `snapshots`.`status`, `date_sent` FROM` (`snapshots`) INNER JOIN `brands` ON `snapshots`.`brand_id` = `brands`.`brand_id` WHERE `snapshots`.`status` = 1 AND `brands`.`status` = 1 AND DATE(date_sent) = '2015-2-9' ORDER BY `date_sent` desc as snapshots) INNER JOIN `brands` ON `snapshots`.`brand_id` = `brands`.`brand_id` WHERE `brands`.`status` = 1 GROUP BY `snapshots`.`brand_id` ORDER BY `date_sent` desc LIMIT 10
```

As you can see the SELECT is within the back apostrophe's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you [group your code](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code--net-8118) first. Write another function subQuery and just execute your mainQuery from there.

Example:

```
Class Example_model Extends CI_Model
{
   function subQuery()
   {
      $query = "SELECT value_2 FROM other_table WHERE id = 2";
      $q = $this->db->query($query);
      $this->mainQuery($q->result());
   } 
   function mainQuery($subQuery)
   {
     $query = "UPDATE some_table SET value_1 = "'.$subQuery.'" WHERE id = 2";
     $this->db->query($query);
   }
}
```

After reading the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), it is stated that:

> $this->db->get();
>
> Runs the selection query and returns the result. Can be used by itself
>   to retrieve all records from a table

I think you have to include the $sub variable inside the quotes.

Comment: thank you. i didnt even think of splitting it up via functions.